# Pandas auto datetime format in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I frequently plot multiple timeseries data from different sources on a single plot, some of which require using matplotlib. When formatting the x-axis, I use matplotlib's `autofmt_xdate()`, but I much prefer the auto formatting of pandas. I'm aware I can manually set the format using `set_major_formatter()`, but the plots I create vary from years, to days in total range, so I would need to adjust the formatting based on each plot. Is there a way to set matplotlib to auto format the x-axis with dates similar to pandas?

I also use interactive plotting, and when using pandas `df.plot()` the x-axis updates when zooming to the respective ranges as shown below, which I would also like to achieve using matplotlib:

[image: pandas format month]
[image: pandas format day]
[image: pandas format inter-day]

Versions:

```
Python: 3.7.1
Pandas: 0.23.3
Matplotlib: 2.2.2
```

**Desired Format:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ix = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', '11/1/2018', freq='D')
vals = np.random.randn(len(ix))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': vals}, index=ix)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[8,6])
df.plot(ax=ax, lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: desired pandas format]

**Current Format:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[8,6])
ax.plot(df, lw=1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: Current matplotlib format]

Comment: Can't reproduce, your first code snippet gives me your "desired" format.

Comment: Yes, this is a simple example just to show the format I want to achieve using matplotlib without requiring `df.plot()`

Comment: MPL really needs to have a copy_formatter() function. It should be easy to implement when the indexes are equivalent. Did you solve it in any way?

Answer (score 5):

An option to show the years in a second row is to use the major and minor ticklabels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, YearLocator, DateFormatter

ix = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', '11/1/2018', freq='D')
vals = np.random.randn(len(ix))
s = pd.DataFrame({'Values': vals}, index=ix)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])
ax.plot(s, lw=1)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("\n%Y"))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter("%b"))

plt.show()
```

If you need the minor ticks for something else, the following would format the major ticks alone - with the same result. Here you would use a FuncFormatter to determine the format depending on the month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

ix = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', '11/1/2018', freq='D')
vals = np.random.randn(len(ix))
s = pd.DataFrame({'Values': vals}, index=ix)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])
ax.plot(s, lw=1)

monthfmt = DateFormatter("%b")
yearfmt = DateFormatter("%Y")

def combinedfmt(x,pos):
    string = monthfmt(x)
    if string == "Jan":
        string += "\n" + yearfmt(x)
    return string

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(combinedfmt))

plt.show()
```

The result is in both cases the same:

[image]

Comment: While this works for plots when the full range is years, it fails to work when the range changes to one month or one day. I also frequently use interactive plots, and this method would not update the x-axis when zooming in. I've updated my question to better reflect this.

Comment: It's sure possible to write your own complete formatter. In case you are interested in that you may read through [this discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10841) about a new general purpose formatter.