# Formatting timedelta on x-axis to HMS if only 1 day

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an x-axis labels of timedelta64[ns] coming out as:

```
0 days 12:01:13.165040
```

How can I achieve the following format if there's only 1 day?:

```
12:01:13
```

If there's more than one day, I need the following format:

```
2018.11.27
```

I've been successful in modifyng the labels by making a function and then calling it with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(xaxisFormat))
```

But I don't know how to exactly go about formatting them.

Comment: Can you find out if there is one or more days and then use the respective formatter? Or are you looking for one single formatter that does it all? There was a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490318/pandas-auto-datetime-format-in-matplotlib)) yesterday, so is there something going on that all of a sudden people need such formatters?

Comment: I could do that yes, how do I find out if there is more than one day? Just check if the last row has a day greater than 0? Also, I don't know how to format the timedelta to either format lol

Answer (score 1):

You could set the respective formatter in dependence of the limits of the plot. This could look as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, HourLocator, DayLocator


def plot_something(h, ax=None):
    td = np.arange(0,h, np.timedelta64(1, "h"))
    y = np.sin(np.linspace(0,h,len(td)))
    t = np.datetime64("2018-11-27") + td
    (ax or plt.gca()).plot(t, y)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)

plot_something(16, ax=axes[0])
plot_something(24, ax=axes[1])
plot_something(40, ax=axes[2])
plot_something(72, ax=axes[3])

def ticking(ax):
    d = np.diff(ax.get_xlim())
    if  d <= 1:
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
    elif d <= 2:
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(byhour=(0,6,12,18)))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
    else:
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y.%m.%d"))

for ax in axes.flat:
    ticking(ax)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]